# Put string between two % in Golang

Tags: go, string-formatting

I have a string in Golang called `mystring` and I want to put it between 2 percentage signs (like this `%mystring%`). However until now I wasn't able to do it.

The things that I have tried are:

```
value := fmt.Sprintf("%%s%",mystring)
value := fmt.Sprintf("%s%s%s","%",mystring,"%")
value := fmt.Sprintf("/% %s/%",mystring)
```

But when I print it, in the end I receive a `nil`. Example: the value of mystring is "HelloWorld" then I get: `%HelloWorld%nil`

Right now I am receiving this as result:

```
/%s/%!(NOVERB)%!(EXTRA string=HelloWorld)<nil>
```

So, what am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: [It's right at the top of the documentation for `fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/): "%% a literal percent sign; consumes no value"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the `%`'s in format string using another `%`:

```
value := fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%",mystring)
```

Comment: Thank you! however it's still returning a nil in the end, something like %HelloWorld%<nil>

Comment: please show your code including initialization/assignment of `mystring`. You have 3 different `Sprintf` in your question, all of them invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Use `%%` in your format string for an actual `%`.

For example:

```
func main() {
    mystring := "hello"
    value := fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", mystring)
    fmt.Println(value)
}
```

Prints: `%hello%`

This is clearly documented at the beginning of the [docs for fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing):

> %%    a literal percent sign; consumes no value